How to achieve bandlimited extrapolation for a discrete noisy signal?
Summary
I'm trying to extrapolate a signal $\mathbf{y}$ sampled at equidistant time points from $-T$ to $T$. From the given experimental conditions, I know that the Fourier Transform of the $\mathbf{y}$  has zero coefficients outside of the frequency ranges from $-\omega_{2}$ to $-\omega_{1}$ as well as from $\omega_{1}$ to $\omega_{2}$.
For the extrapolation, bandlimited extrapolation seems to be the best choice, but I'm struggling to understand it.
I will first explain where the data come from and how they look like and what the aim of the question is. Then, I will explain the problem and what I already tried to solve it (with code).
Data
I'm analysing the data of a Fourier Transform spectrometer (it actually samples in space and not time, but let's ignore this for simplicity). Basically, an interference pattern between two light beams is sampled over different displacements of a moving mirror that moves one of the beams in and out of phase with the other. Typically the obtained signals look as follows (physics-based simulation here; noise-free but the main application should of course involve noisy signals):

They have a characteristic strong burst in the center and slow decays in the left and right wings. Furthermore, they lack periodicity. Since the mirror cannot de displaced indefinitely (like indicated by the black curve), one can only obtain its truncated version over a finite displacement range (red curve).
Another characteristic is that the central burst has an intense signal which may saturate the detector used to acquire it. Thus, this part of the signal is not necessarily reliable and would even distort Fourier Transforms since saturation causes a nonlinear behaviour which violates the assumptions of linearity behind the Fourier Transform. Hence, it would be great to have an extrapolation approach that does not take these values into account, i.e., that can handle outlying or missing data points.
Its Fourier Transform is purely real due to the symmetric simulation (usually complex due to imperfections) and clearly bandlimited. Due to the truncation in the time domain, it is convolved with a sinc function in the frequency domain. It's very hard to choose a prior for a regularized deconvolution in the frequency domain to revert the effect of the convolution with the sinc function given that the Fourier Transform has quite a few very sharp distinct features.

I attached an x-y-y file with an example signal (the first y-column is the theoretical "full" signal and the second y-column is its truncated counterpart; the file has commas as delimiters):
Link to file in the comments ...
Aim
The goal is to achieve super-resolution of the Fourier Transform $\mathbf{Y}$ by extrapolating the signal $\mathbf{y}$ beyond its originally sampled range prior to a final Fourier Transform.
What I tried so far
I first tried to fit an autoregressive model to $\mathbf{y}$, but the signal is not stationary. Only fitting the wings without the central burst was also not really successful. I employed a fast version of the segmented Burg autoregression with Tikhonov regularization (link in the comments), but I don't manage to achieve extrapolation. After the first few oscillation, the deviations are too big and the extrapolation often fades out to zero at some point. Probably, I need quite a lot of coefficients for a decent fit.
Approach in Question - Inversion of the Sinc Matrix
Now, I tried to look into bandlimited extrapolation and found the publication
Mihálik O.: Demystifying band-limited extrapolation
where the author describes that the bandlimited extrapolation can be achieved solving the following problem


...


Question
Why can the bandlimiting be represented by a sinc matrix? I understand this in the continuous case, but for the discrete case this does not add up. The discrete Inverse Fourier Transform of a rectangular function (1 until the maximum frequency, 0 beyond) will not represent a perfect sinc. Actually, the shape can be very different if there is only a few frequencies involved and it only gradually approaches a sinc with increasing number of frequencies. Instead, the Dirichlet kernel seems to be the proper representation. Also, if I understand correctly, the  Papoulis-Gerchberg usually is not formulated with sinc functions like it's done here, but with the FFT-based bandlimiting operation (Fourier Transform, zero frequencies outside the bandlimit, Inverse Fourier Transform).
On top of that, the results of the extrapolation presented in the publication seem quite poor. I partially suspect the Tikhonov regularization to contribute to this because it's a prior to induce sparsity rather than smoothness, but I'm not sure.
All in all, this is a bit confusing to me.
How can the extrapolation be achieved? Both high-level descriptions or worked examples are highly appreciated. I'm also not particularly attached to the approach if there is a better one that's not too computationally demanding.

Additional Code
In case, my current coded approach helps:
So far, I ended up with the following PYTHON code that does not solve the dense matrix of sincs, but uses a sparse matrix solver with Tikhonov regularization. This approach solely relies on matrix-vector products and is thus really fast because the products can simply be computed with FFTs and IFFTs.
For the extrapolation, I computed the convolution kernels by a literal discrete Inverse Fourier Transform rather than the analytical sinc formula. It seems to do the job, but now the extrapolation is periodic (because the convolution kernel is also periodic now) and I'm not sure if that is how it should be.
It should easily generate to the case with a lower and an upper bandlimit as well as higher order derivative Tikhonov regularization.

# === Imports ===

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import rfft, irfft, rfftfreq
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator, lsqr

%matplotlib widget

# === Functions ===


class BandlimitingLinearOperator(LinearOperator):
    """
    Utility class to apply a bandlimiting filter to a signal (rectangular filter in
    frequency domain).

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_points : int
        Number of points in the signal.
    delta_t : float
        Time step of the equidistantly sampled signal.
    band_limit : float
        Frequency up to which the Fourier components should be kept.

    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        num_points: int,
        delta_t: float,
        band_limit: float,
    ) -> None:

        self.num_points: int = num_points
        self.delta_t: float = delta_t
        self.band_limit: float = band_limit

        self.freqs: np.ndarray = rfftfreq(n=self.num_points, d=delta_t)
        self.nonzero_freqs: np.ndarray = self.freqs[self.freqs <= band_limit]
        self.rect_filter: np.ndarray = np.where(
            self.freqs <= band_limit,
            1.0,
            0.0,
        )

        self.shape = (num_points, num_points)

    def _matvec(self, x) -> np.ndarray:
        return irfft(rfft(x) * self.rect_filter, n=self.num_points)

    def _rmatvec(self, x) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.matvec(x)

    @staticmethod
    def from_times(t: np.ndarray, band_limit: float) -> "BandlimitingLinearOperator":
        """
        Creates a BandlimitingLinearOperator from the time points of a signal.

        Parameters
        ----------
        t : np.ndarray
            Time points of the signal.
        band_limit : float
            Frequency up to which the Fourier components should be kept.

        Returns
        -------
        operator : BandlimitingLinearOperator
            The bandlimiting operator.

        """

        return BandlimitingLinearOperator(
            num_points=len(t),
            delta_t=t[1] - t[0],
            band_limit=band_limit,
        )


def solve_extrapolation_problem(
    t: np.ndarray,
    y: np.ndarray,
    band_limit: float,
    damp: float = 1e-10,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, BandlimitingLinearOperator]:
    """
    Solve the bandlimited extrapolation problem using Tikhonov regularization.
    It circumvents the need to compute the dense inverse of the sinc matrix because
    the matrix can be represented as matrix-vector products (linear operator).
    Since these products are based on the Fourier transform, the products can be
    computed cheap and fast without ever constructing the full sinc matrix.

    Parameters
    ----------
    t : np.ndarray
        Time points of the signal.
    y : np.ndarray
        Signal values.
    band_limit : float
        Frequency up to which the Fourier components should be kept.
    damp : float
        The Tikhonov regularization parameter of the ``lsqr`` algorithm.

    Returns
    -------
    coeffs : np.ndarray
        Coefficients of the extrapolated signal.
    mat_A : BandlimitingLinearOperator
        The bandlimiting operator.

    """

    mat_A = BandlimitingLinearOperator.from_times(t=t, band_limit=band_limit)
    coeffs = lsqr(A=mat_A, b=y, damp=damp)[0]

    return coeffs, mat_A


def sinc_equivalent_from_discrete_ift(
    t: np.ndarray,
    nonzero_freqs: np.ndarray,
    center: float,
    num_original_points: int,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Computes the sinc equivalent from an inverse discrete Fourier transform of a
    rectangular bandlimiting filter.

    Parameters
    ----------
    t : np.ndarray
        Time points of the signal.
    nonzero_freqs : np.ndarray
        Nonzero frequencies of the Fourier transform.
    center : float
        Center of the sinc function.
    num_original_points : int
        Number of points in the original signal.

    Returns
    -------
    sinc_equivalent : np.ndarray
        Sinc equivalent of the discrete Fourier transform.

    """

    t_centered = t - center
    sinc_equivalent = np.zeros_like(t)

    # the inverse Fourier transform of the rectangular filter is carried out by
    # summing up the cosine terms with the non-zero frequencies
    for freq in nonzero_freqs:
        # NOTE: only cosine terms are required
        # NOTE: all non-zero frequencies have a mirrored counterpart at -freq, so a
        #       factor of 2 is required to compensate for this
        if freq != 0.0:
            sinc_equivalent += 2.0 * np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * freq * t_centered)
        else:
            sinc_equivalent += 1.0

    return sinc_equivalent / num_original_points


# === Main ===

# --- Constants ---

T_INDICES = np.arange(-500, 500)
T_INDICES_FOR_EXTRAP = np.arange(-700, 700)
DELTA_T = 0.01
BAND_LIMIT = 4.1  # a little more than the highest frequency in the signal
NOISE_LEVEL = 0.5
TIKHONOV_DAMP = 1e-3  # randomly chosen now

# --- Signal  Generation ---

t = T_INDICES * DELTA_T
t_extrap = T_INDICES_FOR_EXTRAP * DELTA_T
y = (
    1.5 * np.cos(1.0 * np.pi * t)
    + np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * t)
    + 0.5 * np.sin(4.0 * np.pi * t)
)
y_noisy = y + NOISE_LEVEL * np.random.randn(y.size)

y_extrap_true = (
    1.5 * np.cos(1.0 * np.pi * t_extrap)
    + np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * t_extrap)
    + 0.5 * np.sin(4.0 * np.pi * t_extrap)
)

# --- Extrapolation ---

# the "sinc matrix equivalent" is solved by a sparse solver
coeffs, op = solve_extrapolation_problem(
    t=t,
    y=y_noisy,
    band_limit=BAND_LIMIT,
    damp=TIKHONOV_DAMP,
)

# then, the sinc matrix equivalent is used to extrapolate the signal
sinc_equivalent_matrix = np.empty(shape=(t_extrap.size, t.size))
for col_index in range(0, t.size):
    sinc_equivalent_matrix[::, col_index] = sinc_equivalent_from_discrete_ift(
        t=t_extrap,
        nonzero_freqs=op.nonzero_freqs,
        center=t[col_index],
        num_original_points=t.size,
    )

extrapolated_signal = sinc_equivalent_matrix @ coeffs

# --- Plotting ---

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t_extrap, y_extrap_true, label="True Signal", color="black")
plt.plot(t, y_noisy, label="Noisy Base to Fit", color="red")
plt.plot(t_extrap, extrapolated_signal, label="Fitted and Extrapolated", color="cyan")

plt.legend()

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel("t", fontsize=16, labelpad=7)
ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=16, labelpad=7)

plt.show()


Link to x-y-y file of simulated data: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rev53zqrmfby76w7fjy50/signal.txt?rlkey=k0hdtfbrkmpluryjge5mcinzo&st=0cp551iw&dl=0

Link to the implementation of the fast segmented Burg algorithm with Tikhonov-regularization: https://github.com/MothNik/pyscopee/blob/0-initial-setup-and-implementation/src/pyscopee/augment/extrapolate/_numpy_base.py#L84-L276

This is only a partial answer because it seems to work, but I didn't get it to run 100% efficiently and reliably yet. I also don't know if the approach I chose is not too unconventional or could be improved.
Maybe it serves as inspiration for a proper answer.
1) Background
My answer is derived based on the thesis
Weidong C., An efficient method for an ill-posed problem - band-limited extrapolation,
Kansas State University, 2007 (currently available with this link)
In chapter 3, the author describes a method to solve the bandlimited extrapolation
problem which is based on fitting the Fourier Transform by a Fourier Transform subject
to a Sobolev norm penalization on the Fourier Transform and its derivative. Later, an
efficient version of the Papoulis-Gerchberg algorithm is derived from this method.
Honestly, I don't understand most of the derivations, but I think the author took some
shortcuts that simplify the problem a little too much - even though these
simplifications result in a computationally efficient algorithm.
First, why is the Fourier Transform of the signal fitted? Usually, each data point in
the time domain has its own uncertainty and the Fourier Transform mixes all these
uncertainties together. So, excluding missing or corrupted data points is no longer
possible since they already corrupted the Fourier Transform in a more or less
untraceable way.
Secondly, why should the Fourier Transform be smooth? While this is a reasonable
assumption for the signal, it's not a given that its Fourier Transform is also smooth. The Fourier Transform in the question is an excellent example for this due to its very sharp features.
All in all, this approach seems a bit inappropriate to me.
2) The proposed approach
2.1) Optimization problem description
The following optimization problem needs to be solved for bandlimited extrapolation
by finding the optimal bandlimited Fourier Transform of a given signal
$f\left(t\right)$.
$f\left(t\right)$ is real-valued and it is only known in the range
$\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$. Now, it needs to be extrapolated to the range
$\left[-U_{l}, U_{u}\right]$ where $U_{l} \lt T_{l}$ and $T_{u} \lt U_{u}$.
Additionally, it is known that the signal is bandlimited, i.e., its Fourier Transform
is zero outside the frequency ranges $\left[-\Omega_{u}, -\Omega_{l}\right]$ and
$\left[\Omega_{l}, \Omega_{u}\right]$ where $0 \leq \Omega_{l} \lt \Omega_{u}$.
The goal is to find the optimal bandlimited Fourier Transform of the signal that is
consistent with the known signal in the range $\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$ and obeys to
some prior knowledge explained in the following. This Fourier Transform can then be
transformed back to the time domain to obtain the extrapolated signal.
2.2) Formulation of the optimization problem
For matrix notations, the following definitions are used:

$\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix
$\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is the transpose of $\mathbf{A}$
$\mathbf{A}^{H}$ is the Hermitian of $\mathbf{A}$ (complex conjugate transpose)
$\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\mathbf{A}$
$\mathbf{a}$ is a vector
$\mathbf{\widehat{a}}$ is the Fourier Transform of the vector $\mathbf{a}$ sampled
at equidistant points $\omega_{j}$ in the frequency domain

Regarding the discretization of the signal, the following definitions are made:

$\mathbf{f}$ is the $\left(n\times1\right)$-vector of the known real-valued signal
$f\left(t\right)$ sampled at equidistant sampling points $t_{i}$ in the range
$\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$ with spacing $\Delta t$
$\mathbf{g}$ is the $\left(m\times1\right)$-vector of the extrapolated signal
$g\left(t\right)$ sampled at equidistant sampling points $\tau_{i}$ in the range
$\left[-U_{l}, U_{u}\right]$ with spacing $\Delta t$ (this range contains all the
sampling points of $\mathbf{f}$)

For solving the optimization problem, the fidelity of $\mathbf{g}$ to $\mathbf{f}$ has
to be maximized by minimizing the  weighted sum of the squared errors between them in
the range $\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$. The criterion to minimize can be written as
$\left(\mathbf{f}^{\left[p\right]} - IFT\left(\mathbf{\widehat{g}}\right)\right)^T\cdot\mathbf{W}_{\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]}\cdot\left(\mathbf{f}^{\left[p\right]} - IFT\left(\mathbf{\widehat{g}}\right)\right)$
where

$\mathbf{f}^{\left[p\right]}$ is the known signal that was padded with arbitrary
values (zeros for simplicity) outside the range $\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$ (enough to
extend it to the range $\left[-U_{l}, U_{u}\right]$, i.e., to increase its length from
$n$ to $m$)
$\mathbf{\widehat{g}}$ is the $\left(m\times1\right)$-vector holding the Fourier
Transform of the estimated extrapolated signal $\mathbf{g}$
(this is the variable to optimize ... for now)
$\mathbf{W}_{\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]}$ is a diagonal
$\left(m\times m\right)$-matrix that holds the reciprocal of the squared standard errors
of $\mathbf{f}$ in the range  $\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$ and zeros elsewhere (to only
enforce the fidelity in the range $\left[-T_{l}, T_{u}\right]$); it will be written as
$\mathbf{W}$ for simplicity
$IFT$ is the inverse Fourier Transform operator

However, maximum fidelity alone will lead to some problems:

the Hermitian symmetry of the Fourier Transform for real-valued signals will not be
considered, thereby doubling the number of variables to optimize
the bandlimitedness will not be enforced
the risk of overfitting is very high - if the system can even be solved in the first
place

These would in theory require additional constraints to be introduced - at the cost of
making the optimization problem computationally expensive. Therefore, a different
approach is needed.
2.3) Removing the bandlimitedness and Hermitian symmetry constraints
The first two points can be tackled by not using the definition of
$\mathbf{\widehat{g}}$ being the full Fourier Transform of $\mathbf{g}$.
Instead, $\mathbf{\widehat{g}^{\left[r\right]}}$ is defined as the Fourier Transform in
the range $\left[\Omega_{l}, \Omega_{u}\right]$ exploiting both

the Hermitian symmetry of the Fourier Transform of real-valued signals
the bandlimitedness of the signal

Looking to the future where the optimization problem has to be solved, the complex
nature of $\mathbf{\widehat{g}^{\left[r\right]}}$ is sort of an additional problem
because this means that a complex solver is needed.
For this reason $\mathbf{\widehat{g}^{\left[r\right]}}$ will be expressed in terms
of the purely real $\left(p\times 1\right)$-vector
$\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$. Let
$\mathbf{\widehat{g}^{\left[r\right]}}$ be defined as the vector
$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\left(\omega_{j}\right) + ib\left(\omega_{j}\right)\\
a\left(\omega_{j+1}\right) + ib\left(\omega_{j+1}\right)\\
\vdots\\
a\left(\omega_{j+k}\right) + ib\left(\omega_{j+k}\right)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
such that

$\Omega_{l} \leq \omega_{j}\ \dots\ \omega_{j+k} \leq \Omega_{u}$,
$\omega_{j-1} \lt \Omega_{l}$, and
$\Omega_{u} \lt \omega_{j+k+1}$

Coefficients for frequencies outside the range $\left[\Omega_{l}, \Omega_{u}\right]$ are
0.
Then, $\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$ can be written as
$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\left(\omega_{j}\right)\\
b\left(\omega_{j}\right)\\
a\left(\omega_{j+1}\right)\\
b\left(\omega_{j+1}\right)\\
\vdots\\
a\left(\omega_{j+k}\right)\\
b\left(\omega_{j+k}\right)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
Mapping $\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$ to the Full Fourier Transform
$\mathbf{\widehat{g}}$ (not just the positive bandlimited part
$\mathbf{\widehat{g}^{\left[r\right]}}$!) can be computed by using
$\mathbf{\widehat{g}} = \mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$
where the $\left(m \times p\right)$-matrix $\mathbf{P}$ - whose frequency order is
chosen to be consistent with numpy.fft.fft
(Link) - looks
like
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ 0 \le \omega \lt \Omega_{l}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
1 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & i & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \Omega_{l} \le \omega \le \Omega_{u}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & i & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 & i & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \Omega_{l} \le \omega \le \Omega_{u}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & i & \ & \ & \ \\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \Omega_{u} \lt \omega\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ -\omega \lt -\Omega_{u}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -i & \ & \ & \ \\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 & -i & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ -\Omega_{u} \le -\omega \le -\Omega_{l}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -i & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -i & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ -\Omega_{u} \le -\omega \le -\Omega_{l}\\
1 & -i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ & \ & \ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ & \ & \ -\Omega_{l} \lt -\omega \lt 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
Within $\mathbf{P}$, there are at maximum two non-zero entries per row. The first entry
extracts the real part while the second entry extracts the imaginary part of the
Fourier Transform, respectively. In case $\Omega_{l} = 0$, special care must be taken
because only the real part may be considered for $a\left(0\right) + ib\left(0\right)$
to avoid redundancy.
So for this special case, the imaginary unit $i$ has to be omitted and there may be
no $b\left(0\right)$ present in $\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$.
Besides, the first half of the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ extracts the coefficients of the
positive frequencies while the second half extracts the coefficients of the negative
frequencies. The Nyquist frequency should not require special treatment because the
bandlimit $\Omega_{u}$ should naturally exclude it.
With this, the operation $IFT\left(\mathbf{\widehat{g}}\right)$ has to be replaced by
$IFT\left(\mathbf{\widehat{g}}\right) = IFT\left(\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}\right)$
Expressing $IFT$ in terms of the $\left(m \times m\right)$-matrix
$\mathbf{F}^{-1} = \mathbf{F}^{H}$, the operation can be written as
$IFT\left(\mathbf{\widehat{g}}\right) = \mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$
where $\mathbf{F}^{-1} = \mathbf{F}^{H}$ is the inverse and at the same time Hermitian
of the Fourier Transform matrix $\mathbf{F}$ (see
Link to
scipy.linalg.dft). $\mathbf{F}$ is square and symmetric, so
$\mathbf{F}^{-1} = \left(\mathbf{F}^{-1}\right)^{T}$ - a fact that will be used later.
In summary, the fidelity criterion can be reformulated as
$\left(\mathbf{f}^{\left[p\right]} - \mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}\right)^T\cdot\mathbf{W}\cdot\left(\mathbf{f}^{\left[p\right]} - \mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}\right)$
that now has to be minimized with respect to $\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$
rather than $\mathbf{\widehat{g}}$.
This criterion naturally enforces the bandlimitedness of the signal without introducing
any further constraints which would be computationally expensive if formulated as actual
constraints. On top of that, the Hermitian symmetry of the Fourier Transform is also
encoded just naturally by the matrix $\mathbf{P}$, so another constraint was removed
and the number of variables to optimize was halved.
2.4) Addressing the overfitting problem
However, the third point regarding overfitting is still not addressed. To tackle this,
multiple solutions are possible. One way is to add a regularization that penalizes
the deviations from a known prior, e.g., that enforces smoothness of the signal. This
can be done by adding a term that penalizes the squared derivative of the signal
$\left(\frac{d^{s}\mathbf{g}}{\left(dt\right)^{s}}\right)^T\left(\frac{d^{s}\mathbf{g}}{\left(dt\right)^{s}}\right)$
where

$\frac{d^{s}\mathbf{g}}{\left(dt\right)^{s}}$ is the $s$-th derivative of
$g\left(t\right)$ with respect to the time $t$ which is computed as a vector of the
$s$-th forward finite differences of $\mathbf{g}$ in this context

Again, this term can be written involving the matrices $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ as
$\left(\mathbf{D}^{s}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}\right)^T\cdot\left(\mathbf{D}^{s}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}\right)$
where $\mathbf{D}^{s}$ is the $\left(m-s\right)\times m$ matrix that computes the
$s$-th order forward finite difference matrix
(Link).
Higher orders $s$ will enforce more natural smoothness of the signal. However, they will
also lead to numerical instability, so typically $s=2$ is a reasonable choice. For this
case, the forward finite difference matrix $\mathbf{D}^{2}$ (will be referred to as $\mathbf{D}$ from here) is given by
$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
An alternative could be Tikhonov regularization. With the definition of the vector
$\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$ the Euclidean norm of the Fourier Transform can
be easily computed as
$\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$
Edit
It is also possible to formulate the derivative penalty in the frequency domain already (the derivative can be computed by a simple multiplication since it is a convolution in the time domain). This would highly simplify the calculations similar to the Tikhonov regularization just described. The only difference would be the need for an additional weighting matrix between the two $\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}$-vectors. However, this approach would suffer from the same problem as the Fourier Transform fitting. The derivative, which can have locally distinct features in the time domain, gets globally "diluted" in the frequency domain. Spatially adaptive smoothing in the time domain, e.g., by assigning individual weights to the derivative depending on the signal's curvature, is not easily possible in the frequency domain.
2.5) Why was this formulation chosen?
Making use of this formulation has several advantages:

the standard errors of $\mathbf{f}$ can be considered individually for each sampling
point to account for heteroscedasticity. This would not be possible in the frequency
domain because the Fourier Transform mixes all errors together. On top of that dealing
with missing or corrupted data is only possible in the time domain and the weights
naturally allow for this option.
the bandlimitedness is enforced without introducing any further constraints
the smoothness of the signal is used as a prior knowledge to prevent overfitting.
In contrast to the signal, it's not a given that its Fourier Transform is also smooth.

All in all, the assumptions are made in the appropriate domain.
2.6) How to solve the optimization problem?
The problem can be formulated as a least-squares problem
$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}}\approx\mathbf{b}$. The
$\left(\left(m + m - s\right)\times p\right)$-matrix $\mathbf{A}$ looks like
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\mathbf{W}}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\\
\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}
\end{bmatrix}
$
where $\lambda$ controls the strength of the derivative penalty and can be found via
cross-validation or the discrepancy principle.
For the signals in the question, $m$ is very large because $n$ is very large (50 000 or more), so forming the
matrix $\mathbf{A}$ explicitly and storing it in memory would be impossible because
due to its size.
Hence, the LSQR algorithm (Link) is an appropriate choice because

it is a matrix-free solver that only requires the matrix-vector products of
$\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ with a given vector $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$,
respectively
it circumvents the need for computing the normal equations
$\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{\widehat{x}^{\left[r\right]}} = \mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{b}$ which would otherwise square the
condition number of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ thereby reducing the numerical stability
(and the system is already ill-conditioned)

For completeness, the right-hand side $\mathbf{b}$ is given by
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\mathbf{W}}\cdot\mathbf{f}^{\left[p\right]}\\
\mathbf{0}
\end{bmatrix}
$
where $\mathbf{0}$ is an $\left(m-s\right)$-vector of zeros.
Now, the only thing left to do is to cast this into an implementation of the
matrix-vector products of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^{T}$. So, what does each
matrix-vector product look like for $\mathbf{A}$ with a generic real
$\left(p\times 1\right)$-vector $\mathbf{x}$:

$\mathbf{P}$ expands the real vector into a $\left(m\times1\right)$-vector of complex
coefficients arranged for the following Inverse Fourier Transform
$\mathbf{F}^{-1}$ computes the Inverse Fourier Transform of these complex coefficients
$\sqrt{\mathbf{W}}$ weights the inverse Fourier Transform
$\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{x}$
computes the penalized $s$-th order finite differences of the inverse Fourier
Transform

So in total, $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{x}$ computes a vertical concatenation of the
weighted inverse Fourier Transform and the penalized $s$-th order finite differences of
the inverse Fourier Transform from the real coefficient representation of the Fourier
Transform in the positive bandlimited range.
However, the matrix-vector product of $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is a bit more complicated because
the transpose operation is not an inversion, so the operations are not simply reverted.
With symmetry of some matrices in mind, the matrix $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is given by
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{P}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\sqrt{\mathbf{W}} & \sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{P}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{D}^{T}
\end{bmatrix}
$
Again, this can be broken down into the following operations for the matrix-vector
product of $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ with a generic real vector $\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{y}_{1}\\\mathbf{y}_{2}\end{bmatrix}$
(encodes something I don't fully understand myself):

$\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\sqrt{\mathbf{W}}\cdot\mathbf{y}_{1}$ computes the Inverse
Fourier Transform of the weighted vector $\mathbf{y}_{1}$ (result will be complex)
$\mathbf{P}^{T}$ compresses this complex Inverse Fourier Transform into real
coefficients that are multiplied with $\pm2$ and have a reversed order (this can be
inferred from writing out the transpose next to an Inverse Fourier Transform and
collecting the individual terms 1))
$\mathbf{D}^{T}$ takes the vector $\mathbf{y}_{2}$, pads it with $s$ zeros on each
side and takes the $s$-th order finite differences of it with the finite difference
coefficients being reversed (this can be inferred from writing the matrix out as well)
1)
$\mathbf{P}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}$ compresses the result of the Inverse Fourier Transform
of the finite differences similar to the first and second step

So in total, when $\mathbf{A}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{y}$ is written as
$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{P}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\sqrt{\mathbf{W}} & \sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{P}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{D}^{T}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{y}_{1}\\\mathbf{y}_{2}\end{bmatrix}$
it shows that the matrix-vector product of $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ with $\mathbf{y}$ computes a
sum (not a concatenation) of two individually processed parts of $\mathbf{y}$
1).
1) It is clearly evident that the operations are not simply reverted by
the transpose operation.
3) Python code
I hereby provide my current draft implementation of this approach. The matrix $\mathbf{P}$ is constructed as a sparse
matrix, but this is still quite inefficient because the coefficient extraction now
involves a lot of multiplication with 1 and $i$ which is not very efficient.
Additionally, it comes with some logic to handle the special case of the lower bandlimit being 0.
In the very bottom, there is a test that produces the following result for the
extrapolation of a noisy test signal:
Link to Python code



Please forgive if I made any typos in all the equations and symbols. I'm happy to correct them if you leave a comment!
